# Swift - Copy completionHandler

Tags: objective-c, swift, background, appdelegate, completionhandler

I have been following a tutorial from Appcoda : http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/ 
but writing it in swift. I have come across this line of code that I cannot get to work in swift

```
-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // Check if all download tasks have been finished.
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        if ([downloadTasks count] == 0) {
            if (appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler != nil) {
                // Copy locally the completion handler.
                void(^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler;

                // Make nil the backgroundTransferCompletionHandler.
                appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = nil;

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // Call the completion handler to tell the system that there are no other background transfers.
                    completionHandler();

                    // Show a local notification when all downloads are over.
                    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    localNotification.alertBody = @"All files have been downloaded!";
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

The part I can't get right is:

```
void(^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler
```

I have the appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler variable but I don't know how to assign it to void(^completionHandler)().
void(^completionHandler)() is not recognised by swift.

Help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Should you replace this void(^completionHandler)() with void(^completionHandler)(void)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably tackle the app delegate, as that's where the definition of the `completionHandler` closure rests. You presumably would define the `backgroundTransferCompletionHandler` property to be a closure which is an optional, perhaps something like:

```
var backgroundTransferCompletionHandler: (() -> ())?

func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    // do whatever else you want (e.g. reinstantiate background session, etc.)
}
```

Then, the Swift rendition of the code you reference in your question would grab the local copy of that `completionHandler` like so:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

let completionHandler = appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler
```

And then to call it:

```
completionHandler?()
```